# iOS Google oAuth userID always nil

Tags: ios, google-oauth

Whenever Google returns to "finishedWithAuth" the userID variable is always nil

Here is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Configure the Google+ Sign In
    var signIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()
    signIn.scopes = ["profile"];
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = true
    signIn.clientID = kClientId
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = true
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID = true

    signIn.trySilentAuthentication()
    signIn.delegate = self
}

func finishedWithAuth(auth: GTMOAuth2Authentication!, error: NSError!) {
    if(error == nil && auth != nil){
        println(auth.userID) // always nil
        println(auth.userEmail) // always contains user's email
    }else{
        println("Recieved error \(error) and auth object \(auth)")
    }
}
```

I can't see what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you add the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, Auth is successful. userID is just nil

Comment: You are using an old library. The new library is here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/